# Implementing run-length encoding

Tags: language-agnostic, compression, run-length-encoding

I've written a program to perform run length encoding.
In typical scenario if the text is

```
AAAAAABBCDEEEEGGHJ
```

run length encoding will make it

```
A6B2C1D1E4G2H1J1
```

but it was adding extra 1 for each non repeating character. Since i'm compressing BMP files with it, i went with an idea of placing a marker "$" to signify the occurance of a repeating character, (assuming that image files have huge amount of repeating text).

So it'd look like

```
$A6$B2CD$E4$G2HJ
```

For the current example it's length is the same, but there's a noticable difference for BMP files. Now my problem is in decoding. It so happens some BMP Files have the pattern `$<char><num>` i.e. `$I9` in the original file, so in the compressed file also i'd contain the same text. `$I9`, however upon decoding it'd treat it as a repeating I which repeats 9 times! So it produces wrong output. What i want to know is which symbol can i use to mark the start of a repeating character (run) so that it doesn't conflict with the original source.

Comment: Who is voting to close?  And why?

Comment: People thought this was a duplicate, because he posted another question about RLE, but they're different questions, and the "dupe" notice was removed

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you encode each `$` in the original file as `$$` in the compressed file?

And/or use some other character instead of `$` - one that is not used much in bmp files.

Also note that the BMP format has RLE compression 'built-in' - look [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm), near the bottom of the page - under "Image Data and Compression".

I don't know what you're using your program for, or if it's just for learning, but if you used the "official" bmp method, your compressed images wouldn't need decompression before viewing.

Answer (score 2):

AAAAAABBCDEEEEGGHJ$IIIIIIIII ==> $A6$B2CD$E4$G2HJ$$I9

If the repeat character occurs in the data, try inserting an extra repeat character in the encoded data.  Then if the decoder sees a double repeat character it can insert the actual repeat character

$A6$B2CD$E4$G2HJ$$I9 ==> AAAAAABBCDEEEEGGHJ$IIIIIIIII

Answer (score 1):

What most programs do to signify that some character needs to be treated literally is that they have a defined escape sequence.

For example, in [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions), the following are specially defined characters that usually have a meaning:

```
^[].*+{}()$
```

Yes, your fun dollar sign character is in there, and it usually means *end of line*.

So what a programmer using regular expressions has to do to have these characters interpreted literally is that they need to express those characters as an escape sequence.  For example, to interpret *$* as *$*, and not *end of line*, the programmer uses *\$*, which is the escape sequence.(1)

In your case, you can store literal dollar signs into your compressed file as *\$*.(2)

1. NB: [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) inverts this logic.
2. The above solutions to store *$* as *$$* becomes confusing when you have runs of *$* in the BMP file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the luxury of being able to scan the entire input before starting to compress it, you could choose the least frequent value in the input as your escape value.
For example, given this input:

```
AAAABBCCCCDDEEEEEEEFFG
```

You could choose "G" as your escape value (or even "H" if it's part of your symbol set) and adopt a convention whereby the first character of the encoded stream is the escape value. So the string above might encode to:

```
GGA4BBGC4DDGE7FFGG
```

or even better:

```
HHA4BBHC4DDHE7FFG
```

Please note that there's no point in encoding a "run" of two identical values because the "compressed" version (e.g. HD2) is longer than the uncompressed version (DD).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that $ is both a symbol for marking a repeat, and also can be a 'BMP' value as well?

If so, what you could do is to mark a double $ ('$$') character to denote that the '$' character should be treated not as a repeat, but as a single '$'. This would of course mean that the '$' is expensive to encode (takes two symbols instead of 1), but would solve your problem.

If you wanted to have a run of the '$' character, you would need to encode it as:
$$$5 - meaning '$' run of '$$'=$, '5' - 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what would possessed someone to use a text-based RLE if they want to compress binary data with it. A BMP is not text.

Right now, since only a single byte is read after the `$`, and it is interpreted as ascii number from 0 to 9, this process has a run length range of 0 to 9, meaning you can only compress values up to 9 repetitions before a new run-length flag needs to be written. After all, you can't make the difference between `$I34` for a run-length of 34, and `$I3` + `4` for a literal `4` behind the repeat of 3.

If this same byte is instead interpreted as *binary* value, it can contain values from 0 to *255*, giving a *massive* difference in efficiency.

As for the escaping of `$` signs themselves, I'd advice either always treating it as repeat of at least 1 (`$$1`), or, better yet, encoding the entire thing differently, with the order of the run length values and the data swapped, so a code becomes `$<length><data>`; then you can use `$0` as special symbol to mean 'just `$`'. When decompressing and encountering the 0 after a `$`, simply don't read on for a third byte. A run length of 0 should never appear in the compressed data anyway, so it can be given a special meaning, but this is useless if the data byte is put first, since then it'd still be the same length as a normal repeat.