# Compression Program in C

Tags: c, run-length-encoding

I want to compress a series of characters. For example if i type

Input : FFFFFBBBBBBBCCBBBAABBGGGGGSSS (27 x 8 bits = 216 bits)
Output: F5B7C2B3A2B2G5S3 (14 x 8 bits = 112bits)

So far this is what i have, i can count the number of Characters in the Array. But the most important task is to count them in the same sequence. I can't seem to figure that out :(
Ive stared doing C just a few weeks back, i have knowledge on Array, pointers, ASCII value
but in any case can't seem to count these characters in a sequence. Ive try a bit of everything. This approach is no good but it the closest i came to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

 int charcnt=0,dotcnt=0,commacnt=0,blankcnt=0,i, countA, countB;
 char str[125];



 printf("*****String Manipulations*****\n\n");
 printf("Enter a string\n\n");

 scanf("%[^'\n']s",str);


 printf("\n\nEntered String is \" %s \" \n",str);


 for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
 {

 // COUNTING EXCEPTION CHARS                         
 if(str[i]==' ')
    blankcnt++;

 if(str[i]=='.')
    dotcnt++;

 if(str[i]==',')
    commacnt++;

 if (str[i]=='A' || str[i]=='a')

  countA++;

      if (str[i]=='B' || str[i]=='b')

  countA++;

 }

 //PRINT RESULT OF COUNT
 charcnt=i;
 printf("\n\nTotal Characters : %d",charcnt);
 printf("\nTotal Blanks     : %d",blankcnt);
 printf("\nTotal Full stops : %d",dotcnt);
 printf("\nTotal Commas     : %d\n\n",commacnt);
 printf("A%d\n", countA);

 }
```

Comment: What does "count them in the same sequence" mean?

Comment: You need to set up an array of counters, one for each possible character you might encounter. Trying to do them separately as discrete variables would be quite unwieldy.

Comment: @ScottHunter I think he wants run length encoding.

Comment: @Delandilon it's fairly obvious what you want to do in the example you showed but you need to say what to do with all the puncuation characters.

Comment: You may also enjoy [this thread at CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/run-length-decoding), on minimal programs to decode the type of output being generated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I've worked out for this assignment- This function was used to do the compression of the string. Hope it help if any still having problem.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

extern compression_function(char arr[1000])

{
   char current_char;
   int count, i,j=0,t=0,G=0,H=0, char_size=0;
   int original_length=0,com_number_length=0,compressed_length=0;
   int index=0;

    FILE* outputfile;
    FILE* processing;

   outputfile= fopen("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\output.txt","w");
   processing= fopen("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\processing.txt","w");

   if(outputfile == '\0' )
{ 
                printf("Cannot Write To File!\n");

                }        


current_char = arr[0]; 
count = 1; 
i = 0; 

printf("\n\nOUTPUT: ");
//USING A WHILE LOOP
while (arr[i] != '\0') 
{ 
//'i' WILL BE INCREMENTED TO CHECK ALL THE CHAR IN THE ARRAY      

i++;

// CHECK IF THE CURENT CHAR IS THE SAME AS THE LAST ONE        
if( arr[i] == current_char )
{
count++; 
}

//ELSE IF NO MORE CHAR IS SIMILAR, IT WILL PRINT THE COUNT RESULT RIGHT AWAY    
else
{
if(count==1)
{ 
//sprintf(output_array,"%c", current_char);             
printf("%c", current_char);
fprintf(outputfile,"%c", current_char);
fprintf(processing,"%c", current_char);

G++;
}

if(count>=2)
{        
       printf("%c%d", current_char, count);
       fprintf(outputfile,"%c%d", current_char,count);
       fprintf(processing,"%c", current_char );
       }

if (count>9)
{
           j++;
           }
           if (count>99)
{
           t++;
           }

//REST ALL COUNT FOR THE SECOND DIFFRENT CHAR IN ARRAY

   current_char = arr[i]; 
   count = 1;
   char_size++;


//BREAK THE LOOP WHEN CHAR IN ARRAY IS NULL       
   if( current_char == '\0' )
   {

           break;

           }   
    } 
    }

 original_length = strlen(arr);
 com_number_length=(char_size+j+t-G);
 compressed_length=(char_size+char_size+j+t-G);

 fclose(outputfile);
 fclose(processing);

 //CALLING FUNCTION-SIZE-CALCULATOR
size_calculator(original_length,char_size,com_number_length,compressed_length);


           }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is called [Run-Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

I think the counting of overall characters and, specifically, of any particular character (e.g. dots, commas, spaces) is an unnecessary distraction if your goal is to simply run-length compress the string.  So let's ignore that for now.

Here's how you can easily do run-length encoding of an ASCII string *in place*.  i.e. the original string will be overwritten with the compressed string.  This may or may not be what you want, but it saves allocation of another buffer and is easy to code.

```
char *compress(char *str) {
    char *start = str;
    char *c_first = str;
    char *c_last = str;
    char *c_write = str;
    int run_len = 0;
    while (*str) {
        ++c_last;
        ++run_len;
        if (!(*c_last) || *c_last != *c_first || run_len == 9) { 
            // end of run
            *(c_write++) = *c_first;
            if (run_len > 1)
                *(c_write++) = '0' + run_len;
            // start next run
            run_len = 0; 
            c_first = c_last;
        }
        ++str;
    }
    *c_write = 0;
    return start;
}
```

If the count or exclusion of any special characters along the way is necessary, you can do that easily within the `while` loop.

Add this to allow testing from the command-line.  Run with your original string as the single argument.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("%s\n", compress(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Your requirements for output are not fully specified, so my assumptions are:

1. *Optimizing assumption:* Runs of length 1 are not compressed. This is easy to detect upon decompression and ensures the compressed string is never longer than the original.  e.g. `"ABBCDEF"` compresses to `"AB2CDEF"` (instead of `"A1B2C1D1E1F1"`)
2. *Simplifying assumption:* Runs longer than 9 characters will be compressed into several pieces. This ensures a run length can always be expressed in a single ASCII digit. i.e. `"AAAAAAAAAAAABBBB"` compresses to `"A9A3B4"`  If you need the output to be `"A12B4"`, it is not difficult.  Remove the `run_len == 9` comparison and expand the code under `run_len > 1` to use `iota` for string rendering.

Comment: Everything you say here is correct, but for someone just starting out with C, I suspect that an in-place implementation is going to be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a counter. Scan the array in a for loop. Keep incrementing the count as long as the array has same sequence of character, as soon as character sequence breaks set the count as the compression number for your last character and set count to 0 to add it again for the next sequence. To check for the sequence you simple put a char variable which keeps value of the last array item and compares it with the next array item in the next loop to see if the sequence breaks.

This is an O(n) algorithm and should be used.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you've got two problems mixed together.

The first, as has been pointed out by @Darren, is called [Run-Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding): look for a sequence of identical bytes, and replace them by a single byte followed by a repeat count.  The second, as far as I can tell, is to count how many of some "special" characters occur in the string.

**Run-Length Encoding**

I'm going to give a different implementation of RLE than @Darren's.  Like his solution, mine doesn't deal with the "special character" parts= of the assignment.  I'm going to start with

```
void
rll_encode(char *in, char *out)
{
    while (*in != '\0') {
        int len = find_run(in);
        out = emit_run(out, *in, len);
        in = in + len;  // advance the input
    }
    *out = '\0';
}
```

This is the skeleton of run-length encoding: move through the input finding runs, and then emits those run into the output, appropriately encoded.  This loop is made up of three steps:

1. The `find_run` function is going to look for the longest allowed run starting at the current location in the input, pointed to by `in`.  It returns the length of that run, which will always be greater than zero.
2. Similarly, `emit_run` takes a character and a repetition count, and generates the correct encoding into the output buffer.  It returns the next location to use in the output buffer.
3. After emitting the run, we advance the pointer into the input buffer by `len` bytes and repeat the loop.

After the loop completes, we append a NUL byte onto the output buffer so it forms a valid string.  In a real compressor of any sort, this last step wouldn't be done, and the input and output buffers would both have sizes associated with them.

The only bits left are to actually implement `find_run` and `emit_run`.  Let's start with `emit_run` as it's a bit simpler:

```
char *
emit_run(char *out, char c, int len)
{
    *out++ = c;
    *out++ = '0' + len;
    return out;
}
```

This takes an output buffer `out`, a character `c`, and it's assocated repeat count `len`.  Given, for example, `c == 'A'` and `len == 5`, it appends `C5` to the output buffer.

There's one fairly serious problem with this function.  Consider what happens to the string `"ABCDE"`: each letter has a repeat count of one, and so the string is encoded as `"A1B1C1D1E1"`, which is hardly very compressed.  There are multiple approaches to this problem, some of which are discussed in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685070/implementing-run-length-encoding), and all of which can be implemented by small changes to `emit_run`.

This leaves us with the problem of finding the runs in the first place.

```
int
find_run(char *in)
{
    char run_char = *in;
    int run_len = 0;
    for (;;) {
        char c = *in;
        bool run_ended = 
            c != *run_char || // catches '\0', too
            run_len == MAX_RUN;
        if (run_ended)
            break;
        run_len++;
        in++;
    }
    return run_len;
}
```

This function is given a place to start scanning, `in`, and returns how many times the first character of the input repeats.

1. Copy the first character of the buffer into `run_char`, and initialize `run_len` to zero.
2. Look at each character `c` in the input, and decide if the run has ended or not.  The run ends if either `c` is not equal to `run_char`, or if the run has hit its maximum length.  Note that checking for `c` not equal to `run_char` also handles hitting the end of the string, ie, `c` is `NUL`.
3. If the run has ended, leave the loop and return the run length.
4. If the run hasn't ended, move forward in the input by one character, and increment the run length.

All these pieces together implement a simple version of run-length encoding.  The following is a skeleton of a small program to test it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_RUN 9

/* insert emit_run from above */
/* insert find_run from above */
/* insert rll_encode from above */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char out[1024];
    rll_encode(argv[1], out);
    printf("%s\n", out);
}
```

I've tried to set up this particular implementation to maximize the clarity of the algorithm, but @Darren's version is closer to what you'd see in production code in that the entire implementation is in one function.  His choice to encode in place is certainly valid, although I think both in-place and separate-output-buffer versions are common.  The former are a bit harder to reason about if you're new to C, and especially pointers.  Also, in any production versions, both the input and output buffers would be given with explicit lengths, and there'd be extra code to check for overflow of the output buffer, both of which I've ignored here.

**Character Counting**

Regarding character counting, don't try to keep a magic variable for each separate special character.  Instead, I'd suggest using an 256-element array to accumulate counts of *all* characters, and then later print out just the entries you want.

This is a fairly easy modification to `find_run` if you use a global array, although again, you wouldn't do it this way in a real implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too long but easy to understand I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* compress(char* str) {
    int i;
    int z = 0;
    int k = 1;
    int size_str = strlen(str);
    char *compress_str = malloc(size_str + 1);
    if (size_str < 2) {
        return str;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size_str; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            compress_str[z] = str[i];
        } else {
            if (str[i] == str[i-1]) {
               compress_str[z] = str[i];
               if ( k >= 9 && k < 99) {
               k++;
               compress_str[z + 1] = (k / 10) + 48;
               compress_str[z + 2] =  (k % 10) + 48;
               } else if (k >= 99) {
                   k++;
                   compress_str[z + 1] = (k / 100) + 48;
                   compress_str[z + 2] =  ((k / 10) % 10) + 48;
                   compress_str[z + 3] =  (k % 10) + 48;
               } else {
                   k++;
                   compress_str[z + 1] = k + 48;
               }
            } else {
                if (k >= 10 && k < 100) {
                    z = z + 3;
                    k = 1;
                    compress_str[z] = str[i];
                } else if  (k >= 100) {
                   z = z + 4;
                   k = 1;
                   compress_str[z] = str[i];
                } else if (k > 1 && k <= 9) {
                    z = z + 2;
                    k = 1;
                    compress_str[z] = str[i];
                } else if (k == 1){
                    z++;
                    compress_str[z] = str[i];
                }
            }
        }
   }
   return compress_str;
}

int main() {
    char* res;
    char* str;
    str = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", str);

    res = compress(str);
    printf("%s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```